# How to represent "Alberich hates everyone but himself" in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I'm currently learning prolog and I'm trying to get the syntax right for "Alberich hates everyone but himself". I suppose I could represent "Alberich hates everyone" as hates(Alberich, X) but how do I represent "but himself"  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specify that `X` is different from `albrich`:

```
hates(alberich, X) :-
    dif(alberich, X).
```

Note that constants start with a lowercase, so you should use `alberich`, not `Alberich`, since `Alberich` is just a *variable* that has as identifier `Alberich`.